# Samsung Oreo(8.0.0) - no such column for video query

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-8.0-oreo, samsung-galaxy

I am repeatedly receiving exception with only on Samsung 8.0.0 devices while querying for videos only. This query is working fine with any other device and other Samsung OS version.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: cloud_server_id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, _data, date_added, date_modified, datetaken, duration, bucket_id, bucket_display_name, width, height FROM video WHERE (date_added >= ?) ORDER BY date_added
```

The projection only contains following columns:

- _id
- _data
- date_added
- date_modified
- datetaken
- duration
- bucket_id
- bucket_display_name
- width
- height

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include the complete Java stack trace, plus your code that is triggering the crash.

Comment: Also reported to Samsung, but no solution there yet https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Product-Updates/New-Android-Oreo-Exception-being-seen-for-Video-based-queries/td-p/349748

Comment: Deleting cache and data in the media storage worked for me. https://www.windowsdigital.com/facebook-messenger-error-loading-media/

Answer (score -2):

[MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns) does not specify this column so you are in no way guaranteed for it to exist.